# Rails Simple Form input not rendering on products#index or #show pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, rendering

I am creating a simple marketplace app and have used simple_forms to add the option for users to create product listings that are then displayed in tables on the product#index page and can be edited, deleted or viewed from there.

The problem is that while the forms will work as requested and redirect me to the product#index page, the input ive added (description, name, price, category) these params are not being displayed and remain as blank on the screen, but a slot in my products table is taken up.

[image: image attached is products#index]

Please see my controller code below:

````
    before_action :set_product, only: %i[ :create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]

    helper_method :profile

    # GET /products or /products.json
    def index
      @products = Product.all
    end
  
    # GET /products/1 or /products/1.json
    def show
      @product = Product.find_by(params[:product_id])
    end
  
    # GET /products/new
    def new
      @product = Product.new
    end
  
    def seller_id
      current_user = Seller.id
    end
  
    # POST /products or /products.json
    def create
      @product = Product.create(params[:product_id])
      if @product.save!
        redirect_to products_path(@product)
      end
    end
  
    def update
        @product = Product.find_by(product_params[:product_id])
            if @product.update(product_params)
                redirect_to products_path(@product)
            end
    end
  
    # DELETE /products/1 or /products/1.json
    def destroy
        @product = Product.delete(params[:id])
        redirect_to products_path
    end
  
    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def params_product
            @product = Product.find_by(params[:id])
        end
    
        # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
        def product_params
            params.permit(:name, :description, :price, :category, :picture, :buyer_id, :seller_id, :product_id)
        end
end```

Product.rb (commented out validations as they kept causing errors):
```class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "Profile", optional: true
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: "Profile", optional: true
  has_one :picture

  # validates_presence_of :name, presence: true
  # validates_presence_of :Description, presence: false
  # validates_presence_of :Price, presence: true
  # validates_presence_of :Category, presence: true
  # validates_presence_of :Picture, presence: true
end```

routes:
```Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    resources :products, only: [:show, :new, :destroy, :create, :update, :index, :edit] 
    resources :pictures, :image_url
    devise_for :users
    root 'home#page'
    get "/products", to: "products#index"
    post "/products", to: "products#create"
    get "/products/new", to: "products#new"
    get "/products/:id/edit", to: "products#edit"
    put "/products/:id", to: "products#update"
    get "/products/:id", to: "products#show"
    delete "/products/:id", to: "products#destroy"
end
````

view:
-create

```
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :Description %>
    <%= f.input :Price %>
    <%= f.input :Category, collection: ["footwear", "accessories", "menswear", "womenswear"] %>
    <%= f.file_field :Picture %>

  </div>
  
  <p>
  <%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
  </p>
<%end%>
```

-edit

```
    <h1 class="heading">Edit Product</h1>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :name %>
      <%= f.input :Description %>
      <%= f.input :Price %>
      <%= f.input :Category, collection: ["footwear", "accessories", "menswear", "womenswear"] %>
      <%= f.file_field :Picture %>
      <%= link_to 'Submit', product_path, method: :patch %>
    </div>
    <p>
    <%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
    </p>
  <%end%>
```

EDIT: Index html file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Products</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Seller</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @products.each do |f| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.name %></td>
        <td><%= f.Description %></td>
        <td><%= f.Price %></td>
        <td><%= f.Category %></td>
        <td><%= f.seller_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', product_path(f), method: :get %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(f), method: :get %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Delete product", product_path(f), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this product?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path, method: :get %>
</html>
```

Any help on the above would be greatly appreciated as I am a beginner to rails.

Comment: Check my answer below. I've listed all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1:**

In your `product_controller`, `def create`,

you created product with `@product = Product.create(params[:product_id])`.

It should be `@product = Product.create(product_params)`

**Issue 2:**

There are too many inconsistencies in your code. In the product `_form`, you used `Description` (upper `D`), but in controller product_params you're permitting `description` (lower `D`). Case sensitivity is the issue. It's not recommended to use camel cased table columns. Keep them lowercased.

**Issue 3:**

You're permitting parameters: `params.permit(:name, :description....)`

WRONG!

Right way: `params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description....)`

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried that and it still results in forms being submitted but their input not showing as above.. is there anything else you could see that may be causing this?

Comment: In your products list view file maybe problem. 
You can edit your answer and post both the view file and the request logs when you submit the form for creating a new product.

Comment: @SnehaBhamra There are too many inconsistencies in your code. In the product `_form`, you used `Description`, but in controller `product_params` you're permitting `description`. Case sensitivity is the issue. 
It's not recommended to use camel cased table columns. Keep them lowercased.